# Which sentence is correct secret/secrets

Tags: phrase-usage

I'm not English native speaker and debating with a friend that is also not native English speaker.

Which of the following sentence is the correct one?

a) I don't have any secret

b) I don't have any secrets

Is "secret" countable or uncountable noun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only "I don't have any secrets" is correct. Secret is a countable noun.

> 1 [countable] something that is known about by only a few people and
>   not told to others

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/secret_2